# sbt resolver for confluent platform

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, sbt, confluent-platform

I am unable to add confluent repo in my sbt. I looked at [pom example](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/clients.html)  and found definition of adding repo in maven.

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>confluent</id>
    <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
  </repository>

  <!-- further repository entries here -->

</repositories>
```

and dependencies

```
<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cp1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- further dependency entries here -->

</dependencies>
```

I used

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("confluent", url("http://packages.confluent.io/maven/")) in build.sbt`
```

and declared dependencies as

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "2.0.0-cp1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "2.0.0-cp1"
```

I still get

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;2.0.0-cp1: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.kafka#kafka_2.12;2.0.0-cp1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

what should be the correct way of doing it?
My build.sbt

```
name := "kafka-Test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.3"


resolvers += Resolver.url("confluent", url("https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"))

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "2.0.0-cp1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "2.0.0-cp1"
```

Comment: You only need Kafka-clients dependency

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is in your resolver definition. It should be:

```
resolvers += "confluent" at "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
```

I just tried this and it works.